# Openvpn Raspberry PI login loop

Tags: authentication, raspberry-pi, openvpn

Suddenly my nordvpn through openvpn on my raspberry pi isn't working anymore. Now I get the following error:

```
Sun Sep 13 12:25:14 2020 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Sun Sep 13 12:25:14 2020 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Sun Sep 13 12:25:14 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]62.112.11.159:443
Sun Sep 13 12:25:14 2020 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Sun Sep 13 12:25:14 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]62.112.11.159:443 [nonblock]
Sun Sep 13 12:25:15 2020 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]62.112.11.159:443
Sun Sep 13 12:25:15 2020 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Sun Sep 13 12:25:15 2020 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]62.112.11.159:443
Sun Sep 13 12:25:15 2020 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Sun Sep 13 12:25:15 2020 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Sun Sep 13 12:25:15 2020 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

No idea what to do. I can't find any server log. Tried removing and reinstalling. Tried updating. I can connect to the internet. It's just when I try to connect to a OVPN file it does this in a loop. I can even give a wrong login information and it won't say anything. Can anyone shine some light on this? Thanks

Comment: You could try 1) upping the log level in OpenVPN if you can, to see if you can get any more information; 2) connecting to the same VPN account from a different device to see if it is just this Raspberry Pi; or if neither of those work 3) talk to your VPN provider to check everything's OK with the service and with your account.

Comment: Well it was working for months and suddenly it won't connect. I can't find any log files. How can I analyse the data?

Comment: I don't think there's anything useful here to analyse, no. You successfully make a connection and then the connection is reset, presumably by the remote end. It'll be an SSL connection so you won't be able to see what data was sent using tcpdump or similar. I'd be surprised if you can't get any more details from OpenVPN, but I don't know it to tell you where to look or where to configure logging. So if you can't find that yourself you'll have to talk to your VPN provider to check your settings and your account are correct.

Comment: Hey, I found the problem! After consulting with nordvpn they found out the the server I was trying to connect was offline. I already tried like 10 server but apparently they are all down. Downloaded a new server OVPN connection file and then it was working!